# Struts1 Output util.Date according with specific format in <html:text> for different Locale

Tags: java, date, date-format, struts-1

I use Struts 1.

And have next bean

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Event {
     private String name;
     private Date date;
     // getters & setters
}
```

And form

```
public class Holiday {
    private Event event;
    // getters & setters
}
```

I have jsp for adding new holiday

```
<html:text name="holidayForm" property="event.date" altKey="date.pattern" maxlength="10" size="10" /></label>
```

And I cant get date or put default date as `Date date = new Date();` in particular format on jsp.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than making your field a `Date`, make it a `String` that represents the date in the correct format. You can use the `SimpleDateFormatter` class to convert between the two. You could also take a look at the [jQuery UI Datepicker module](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) (Javascript, so it will run client-side) to allow your users to select a date (in the correct format), rather than typing it in themselves.

Struts 1 form bean properties are almost always Strings because the built-in type conversion is quite limited. If you map a text input directly to a Date field in your form bean class, the value is expected to be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` and you'll get an Error 500: beanUtils.populate error if it doesn't match.